# Javascript click Listener getting Classes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an easy animation using click eventlistener but i would like to create it getting classes instead of ids. I would like whenever someone click the button to open the box and when it is clicked again to close it. I have tried it with ids and its working but when i use only classes it doesnt. What is the problem?

Thanks.
html code:

```
<div class = "box"></div>
<button class = "btn">Click</button>
```

css code:

```
body {
  background:grey;
}

.box{
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  background:orange;
}

.box.active {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:orange;
}
```

javascript code:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", openFunction, false);

function openFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    if ( y.className === "active" ){
      y.className = "";
    }else{
      y.className = "active";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

1. document.getElementsByClassName returns an array so you have to access the array to add an Event Listener. Something like: `btn[0].addEventListener`
2. On the openFunction() again you have to access the returned array by getElementsByClassName.
3. If className is active you remove all the classes from the object including **box** class. So when you click again it would not find that element.

Check a demo here for vanilla JS:

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
btn[0].addEventListener("click", openFunction, false);

function openFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    if ( y[0].className === "box active" ){
      y[0].className = "box";
    }else{
      y[0].className = "box active";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background:grey;
}

.box{
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  background:orange;
}

.box.active {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box"></div>
<button class = "btn">Click</button>
```

If you want to use Jquery you can try the toggleClass.

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/): This is equivalent to addClass when the class is not present and removeClass when the class is present.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `htmlCollection` which doesn't have a method `addEventListener`. If you have only one single element, consider to give it an `id` and use the same code you have, but change all occurences of `document.getElementsByClassName()` to `document.getElementById()`, or use

```
document.getElementsByClassName()[0].addEventListener(...)
```

If you have multiple elements you want to add an event to, you'll need to loop through them.

ID Example:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", openFunction, false);

function openFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("box");

    if ( y.className === "active" ){
      y.className = "";
    }else{
      y.className = "active";
    }
}
```

If you want to use it with classes, there are a few things to consider. Like stated above, you'll need to pick an element or loop through all to assign event listeners or change their classes. Also, if your code were working, it would work only once as you're overriding the class if it doesn't have the `active` class. Below will work for you:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
btn[0].addEventListener("click", openFunction, false);

function openFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

    if ( y.classList.contains("active") ){
      y.classList.remove("active");
    }else{
      y.classList.add("active");
    }
}
```

Or much easier:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
btn[0].addEventListener("click", openFunction, false);

function openFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
  y.classList.toggle('acitve');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mmm but the problem is that i want to make it with classes. I have already created it with ids and its working but i was wondering how i could achieve it with classes.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements that share a class? @NoName84

Comment: no just those 2 but i want to use only classes instead of ids just to see an example of how it can be done so ill be able to use it in future projects. In my projects i am mostly using classes instead of ids that is why i want to learn how to work with classes

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following, much more efficient/cleaner:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var active = false;
btn[0].addEventListener("click", openFunction, false);

function openFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  active = !active;
  y[0].className = active ? 'box' : 'box active';
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/ZWbmGG)

Link in case anyone is wondering how ternary operator works:

[Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

Also a good read by Douglas Crockford :

[Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Also, here is  performance test in [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-switch).